# Transfer data to onSuccess() method

Tags: java, multithreading

In the following code I write the result of a procedure into a Text field. The code is executed as part of a task.

I want “transfer” text (String “test”) to onSuccess() method, so that I can use it within onSuccess(). I do not want to do that via static / global variables.

My question is: can I transfer data to the onSucess() method?

```
private void recognizeTextFromImage(InputImage image) {

  String test = “Test“

  TextRecognizer recognizer = TextRecognition.getClient(TextRecognizerOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);
  Task<Text> task = recognizer.process(image);
  // recognizer.process(image)
  task
    .addOnSuccessListener(
      new OnSuccessListener<Text>() {
      @Override
      public void onSuccess(Text texts) {
        recognizedText = processTextRecognitionResult(texts);
        editText_Test.setText(test + recognizedText);
        Log.d(TAG,"Successful: " + recognizedText);
      }
    })

    .addOnFailureListener(
      new OnFailureListener() {

    }
  });
  recognizer.close();
}
```

Comment: Did you actually run the code you pasted? You can just use `test` in there. It'll work fine.

Comment: Yes :-) But variable "test" is some kind of "global". If another caller starts the method, the data will be overwritten and the "old" thread would get the wrong data. I need this data and variable "locally".

Comment: Right before `task.addOnSuccessListener(...`, write: `String myTest = test;` and then use `myTest`.

Comment: @rzwitserloot, thank you. Is there a difference to my code? Maybe I did not understand you correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable "test" is not some kind of "global". It is a local variable by definition, and as such, a new one will be instantiated every time a caller starts the method. I can see no concurrency issue with just using the test variable within onSuccess, unless TextRecognizer is implemented in some really weird way.

Comment: Yes. Thank you. My fault. It works now as expected.